# Divide allocated memory between threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, malloc

I have some allocated memory which I need to divide between threads. I write program on linux virtual machine and I use pthreads. I don't understand how to do it.

For example I allocate memory for 5 threads (2 int places for each thread):

```
all_mem = (int*)malloc(5 * 2 * sizeof(int));
```

and I want each of them to write two int values to their own part of the memory. If I have pointer to beginning of the memory, how can I get pointer to some other part of the memory?

Comment: It's going to be hard to answer this without more context.   Why don't you have each thread allocate it's own memory?  If they have to be done on one thread, why not two allocations, one for each thread?  Or if this is not about threads, but about how to address pieces of memory, that's called "pointer arithmetic" and there's lots of info on that around.

Comment: Assuming `int *all_mem;`, `&all_mem[2 * i]` points to the memory for the `i`th thread (counting from 0).

Comment: Without details of how you thread, it is difficult for us to help you. Do you use pthreads or openmpi? Is this program intended to run on shared or distributed memory hardware?

Comment: @BobJacobsen, I have task to allocate the memory in the main program and already allocated memory divide between threads. At least the subject to learn threading.

Comment: @newkid, I use pthreads and I only started to learn them. I do this program on linux virtual machine.

Comment: @IanAbbott, thank you. I guess it solves my problem.

Comment: Take a look at thread local storage (TLS) when you get a chance.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, thread-local storage sometimes is a cheap way to turn a single-threaded library that uses `static` variables into a thread-agnostic library. But, for new code, I would go with an object-oriented design in which different threads are given pointers to different objects to operate on. Pretty much every bad thing that can be said about `static` mutable storage also applies to thread-local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working example which allows you to do that. The general idea is to create a thread, pass an index (its id) to it. Then you can use this id to limit access to specific indices in your array.

In the example below, `a` is the array whose elements are summed in four threads. `Thread0` can access a[0:4], `Thread1` can access a[4:8], `Thread2` a[8:12] and finally `Thread3` a[12:16]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h> 

// size of array 
#define MAX 16 

// maximum number of threads 
#define MAX_THREAD 4 

int a[] = { 1, 5, 7, 10, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30, 64, 110, 220 }; 
int sum[] = { 0 , 0, 0, 0}; 

void* sum_array(void *arg) 
{
  int tid = *((int *)arg);
  for (int i = MAX_THREAD*tid; i < MAX_THREAD*tid + MAX/MAX_THREAD; i++) {
    printf("Thread %i is handling %i \n", tid, i);
    sum[tid] += a[i];
  }
} 

// Driver Code 
int main() 
{ 

    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREAD]; 

    // Creating 4 threads 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++) {
      int *arg = malloc(sizeof(int));
      *arg = i;
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sum_array, (void*)arg); 
    }

    // joining 4 threads i.e. waiting for all 4 threads to complete 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    // adding sum of all 4 parts 
    int total_sum = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++) {
      total_sum += sum[i]; 
    }

    printf("sum is %i \n", total_sum); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how does this work. I am really new to threading. I thought I allocate memory for 5 threads, create them, then somehow pass to thread starting pointer and ending pointer of the memory block and already in thread function write it. Is it wrong way?

Comment: Answered with a minimal example. Have a look

Comment: thank you for such clear example but here memory is allocated for each thread. I need memory to be allocated only once but I guess I can make it now to work thank to your answer.

Comment: Glad that it helps. memory in this case is allocated just once when we declare and initialise `a`.